# iOS swift open file with default application

Tags: ios, swiftui

Dears,

I have this app (currently running only in the iPod Touch 7th gen simulator on iOS 14.4) that is suppose to download some wildly used file types (images, PDFs, ebooks, text files) just simply open them in the same way a user would do with when taping on an item in the Files app.
Now I do manage to download the files (they are usually place somewhere under ///Users/Joe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC7F11C6-87C1-4536-80E5-E5E1C8C6653C/data/Containers/Data/Application/762140F3-76B0-44D1-AD48-0C89B2AAA150/Documents/ folder" but when I launch the open action nothing much happens.
For a jpeg file I would expect some IPhoto (or whatever) application to open, at least it does when I tap on a jpeg file in the Files app

```
    func testFunc(fileURL: URL) {
        myLog("testFunc called with: \(fileURL)")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(fileURL) {
            myLog("Can open URL : \(fileURL)")
            UIApplication.shared.open(fileURL, completionHandler: {success in
                myLog("URL open action success status: \(success)")
            })
        }
        myLog("testFunc dbg_001")
```

Now, according to the my logs the **canOpenURL** gives a green light (true) but when I call **open** nothing happens and the success status is **false** (so it fails)

Do I misunderstand how **UIApplication.shared.open** is suppose to work ?
Isn't it suppose to open my file with some default app ?
I did check and via Files at least I can open pdf or jpeg files.

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.open` will attempt to open a url, but you cannot provide it with a file url; a file url will refer to a file in your app's sandbox , which other apps cannot access.

Comment: Right. I suspect I'm being cheeky now but what is right way to achieve this (open a default file viewer for each file type) ?
I can just compare with android where with a fairly small amount of code (some pfaffing around with MimeTypes and Intent) one can launch a default viewer app for a specific file type or let the user to choose an app to view the file..

Comment: You could let the user save the file to Files via a UIDocumentPickerViewController. Then they could open the file from the Files app (but this is two steps) or you can use a UIActivityViewController to "share" the file to another app.